# Get Div from external website with SIMPLE HTML DOM

Tags: php

I am trying to get some data from a hotel website using simple-html-dom.php script. The problem is that when i'm getting the data and echo thr $html it shows a page where a captcha code is needed, so i guess the website has a security system.

My code is :

```
$html = file_get_html('mylink.com');
echo $html;
```

And the image i get from that $html is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3lQn.png 
i have only take the picture of the verification.

How do i solve this problem ? Can be done using hmtl dom ? ir do i need to use cURL ? Is this possible with cURL ?

Comment: The whole idea behind capthas is that this won't work. But if you would manage to download the image, recognise the text through code, and fill in the answer, then Google will probably hire you.

Comment: When you only get that captcha code when you use the `file_get_html()` function and not in your browser, you can give it a try with cURL. With cURL you can set the user agent string, use cookies, pretty much everything a browser does when requesting that website.

Comment: What do you mean not in my browser ? that page show up in my locahost/ when i echo the $html.